# Git error "fatal: pathspec 'hello.rb' did not match any files"

Tags: git

I'm currently working on the Git Immersion tutorial to get familiar with the fundamentals and I've hit kind of a stump early on. For some reason, whenever I use the command `git add hello.rb`, it returns this error:

```
fatal: pathspec 'hello.rb' did not match any files
```

[image: Here's the problem I'm having]

Comment: Does the file hello.rb actually exist? If it does, is it located in the same directory that holds the git repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 different paths open

Your terminal is `~/hello` and your editor is `git_tutorial/hello`  so that is why you cannot find hello.rb in the terminal, as you are in a different directory.